# Are these farewells formal?

Tags: word-usage, formal

Are these farewells formal?

> A dopo 
>   A tra poco 
>   A presto 
>   A domani

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 3):

The forms of salutations you cite are very common and colloquial. They  are typically used with friends and people you are familiar with. 
They are similar to the more  internationally known forms such as:

> ciao

and

> arrivederci.

A few of the above forms are defined by De Mauro Dictionary

1) ***[A dopo](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/a-dopo) , 2) [A più tardi](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/a-piu-tardi), 3) [A presto](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/a-presto)***